# Meaning and purpose of life in Islam?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, life

Lately I have been really disappointed by my life. Nothing goes as I have planned and I fail in almost everything I do.

I feel like I am failing in this life and as I am not a good Muslim (I do not pray 5 times a day or follow the path of sunnah) I will fail in my after-life too.

So lately I have been wondering about the purpose of life. Were we humans only created so we could go about living our lives, praying 5 times a day, follow the path of sunnah and then just die?

Even if we all go to Jannah and live happily forever, what then?

Why were we humans created? Is there a bigger-than-life purpose of our existence?

P.S. please don't say that my Imaan is not strong or as I don't pray 5 times a day, that is why I am failing in this life. I know a lot of people who are really bad i.e. they do not have morals. They cheat, bribe, consume alcohol and do adultery and still they are living a damn happy life. You may say that they will be dealt with in the after-life or burn in hell, but hey...I may not be doing those things but still I am not doing right things that will get me to Jannah (praying etc) and I also do things that will surely get me to hell like listening to music, lying etc so if we both are going to burn in hell (the duration period in hell might be different but that we don't know for sure), aren't those people who live happily here better?

Comment: See also: [What is the Meaning of Life](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/42879/what-is-the-meaning-of-life)

Answer (score 1):

I may sound weird or confusing, sorry for that!
Your Question has something to it which makes it being asked as **wrong**, I mean it is like someone gives you a gift (letting you be and exist) and tells you how to use it or that gift will be broken.

- You can't ask what is the purpose of this gift! he just gave you something, you are the one to decide what to do with it.
- He didn't give you the gift so that to break it if you didn't use it as expected or to reward you (having a nice gift). It is just a result of your own actions [if needed I Explained more in 1]
- One can't say I never wanted this gift to be given to me; That "I" didn't exist without the gift of life and it was shaped with that gift. It's like saying "I wanted to never want" he is contradicting his existence.
- You should consider you were given that gift out of love. The one who gave it to you wants you to be closer to him and would be offended if you ever break his gift.
- Taking care of a gift (living a good life ) is not the goal, Your friendship (getting as close as you can to God) is the goal.

As Allah mentions in Quran he only created us for worshiping him, that as the Arabic sentence says is not about just bending down five times a day and ... It is about being an "Abd" meaning someone who thinks about God and does as he wants to a extent that he forgets himself. God wants us to get as close to him as possible.

---

1- heaven and hell is a result of our life (our test), God is righteous! So, we get the result of our deeds. Not that God created us to wait there and punish the bad and let the good enter heaven to eat as mush as he wants. Getting that gift in my example and keeping it to show everyone was not the goal, it was just a tool to get you close to the one who gave it to you. Heaven is the **result** of our good life but **the goal is God** to get more closer to him.

Answer (score 0):

God created humans and other creatures to worship him, that already has been said in the Quran, just read it.
Everything god created in this universe to help us have a better life and serve us to build the earth, and use our minds to know how great and powerful he is.

So, why he need us to worship him, and why we have to be good and do everything right?
Just because he want to give us all the blesses we can think about, and much more than we can think that all exist in heaven.
So, if we where not good and did not worship him, then we don't deserve all that blesses.

On the other side, if we don't worship him, and we where very bad with each other, he will punish us twice.
First one in this life, just like what is happening to you, so you can realize that god exist, and there will be consequences for your actions.
If you changed your life will be changed, if not you will be punished at hell.

Comment: So we humans were only created so God Almighty could punish us for our crimes (not following his orders) or reward us if we obey? that is the purpose of human life? *Forgive me if my question sounds disrespectful*

Comment: To reward us if we obey. But if we did not obey him and did something wrong, he will give us a small punishment to remind us that we are doing something wrong, and go back to doing the right things.

Comment: Being rewarded or punished by God, is all because of our actions, our actions decide if we will be rewarded or punished. And by the way, if we were doing bad things, and then realized that and wanted to change and do everything right and committed to that, then God will forgive us for all the past.