# What is the purpose of our birth and life according to Quran?

Tags: islamic-philosophy

I have heard that solution to every problem is present in the Qur'an. I want to ask: What is the purpose of our birth and life according to the Qur'an? If anyone can give me the reference verse(s) from Quran, I shall be very grateful to him/her.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaning and purpose of life in Islam?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12230/meaning-and-purpose-of-life-in-islam)

Comment: It is not possible duplicate. I have asked for  verses from Quran. I have not asked for any persons opinion as they are given in the question you suggested I duplicated from.

Answer (score 4):

The relevant verse is [Qur'an 67:2](http://quran.com/67/2)

> He Who created Death and Life, that He may try which of you is best in deed: and He is the Exalted in Might, Oft-Forgiving;-

In another [ayah](http://quran.com/51/56), Allah says

> I have not created man or jinn except that they should worship Me

There are several similar verses in the Qur'an. Essentially, the purpose of our life and death is to worship God, and this is ahead of any other thing.

Answer (score 3):

**بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم**

the purpose of creations is 3 things :

**1st : Tests and examinations**

Allay says [Surat Al-Mulk - 2]:

> [He] who created death and life to test you [as to] which of you is best in deed - and He is the Exalted in Might, the Forgiving -

in this verse, the creation, testing and examine the humans is introduced as a purpose .

**2nd : knowledge**

Allah says [Surat Aţ-Ţalāq - 12]

> It is Allah who has created seven heavens and of the earth, the like of them. [His] command descends among them so you may know that Allah is over all things competent and that Allah has encompassed all things in knowledge.

as you might see in this verse knowing the will, knowledge and the power of god is shown as a purpose .

**3rd : Divine Mercy**

Allah says [Surat Hūd - 118,119]

> 118: And if your Lord had willed, He could have made mankind one
>   community; but they will not cease to differ.
>
> 119 : Except whom your Lord has given mercy, and for that He created
>   them. But the word of your Lord is to be fulfilled that, "I will
>   surely fill Hell with jinn and men all together."

in this verse you see a main objective of creation, and that is the divine mercy .

**Conclusions**

All the verses we are talking about is just a declaration of devotion and reverence and clearly they introduce these two purposes as the main reason of creation .