# What is the ultimate purpose of Islam?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, belief

As everything has its purpose, what is the purpose of this religion? Is it really serving its purpose now or not? Knowing that we can interpret, understand and, if possible, practice its teachings better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaning and purpose of life in Islam?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12230/meaning-and-purpose-of-life-in-islam)

Comment: Purpose of religion itself is different from purpose of life according to it. Why it exists in first place, it is not purpose of life.

Answer (score 1):

Purpose of Islam is very great and large it can't be explain in a question, I can just make a very very brief main points.

1- To bring peace among people(`The Qur'an is a heavenly message and the programme of our lives. Allah in His Mercy sent this book of light and guidance to mankind through His Prophet Muhammad (s.a.w.).`).

2- For worshiping to a single true god Allah as there is no god but Allah as mentioned in the Quran. And He is the one who created us.
3- To show the right path to the people.

4- To show how to live.

5- Prophet Mohammad (peace be upon him) said: "I have been sent to perfect the best of manners".[source](http://www.questionsaboutislam.com/faith-beliefs-practices/islam-teaches-manners.php)
see more
http://www.coiradio.com/library/special/youth/prophets/213islam.htm

etc..

> Is it really serving its purpose now

Yes it is and Insha-allah it will till the day of judgment or till Allah wants.

looking to some imperfect muslim's you cant say that it is not serving its purpose. Islam is perfect muslims are not so if anybody not walk on the path of islam so it is his problem not the problem in Islam.

And Allah and his Messenger knows best.